# How to get the calculate the RGB values of a pixel from the luminance?

Tags: c++, math, libjpeg

I want to compute the RGB values from the luminance.

The data that I know are :

- the new luminance (the value that I want to apply)
- the old luminance
- the old RGB values.

We can compute the luminance from the RGB values like this :
`uint8_t luminance = R * 0.21 + G * 0.71 + B * 0.07;`

My code is :

```
// We create a function to set the luminance of a pixel
void jpegImage::setLuminance(uint8_t newLuminance, unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {

  // If the X or Y value is out of range, we throw an error
  if(x >= width) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Error : in jpegImage::setLuminance : The X value is out of range");
  }
  else if(y >= height) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Error : in jpegImage::setLuminance : The Y value is out of range");
  }

  // If the image is monochrome
  if(pixelSize == 1) {

    // We set the pixel value to the luminance
    pixels[y][x] = newLuminance;
  }

  // Else if the image is colored, we throw an error
  else if(pixelSize == 3) {
    // I don't know how to proceed
    // My image is stored in a std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> pixels;

    // This is a list that contain the lines of the image
    // Each line contains the RGB values of the following pixels
    // For example an image with 2 columns and 3 lines
    // [[R, G, B, R, G, B], [R, G, B, R, G, B], [R, G, B, R, G, B]]

    // For example, the R value with x = 23, y = 12 is:
    // pixels[12][23 * pixelSize];
    // For example, the B value with x = 23, y = 12 is:
    // pixels[12][23 * pixelSize + 2];
    // (If the image is colored, the pixelSize will be 3 (R, G and B)
    // (If the image is monochrome the pixelSIze will be 1 (just the luminance value)
  }
}
```

How can I proceed ?
Thanks !

Comment: You can't compute color from luminance alone. You need three attributes, as in [Hue + Saturation + Luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). Are you asking instead "how can I lighten or darken a color"?

Comment: You should note that "luminance" has a precise meaning; it's the amount of light that reaches the viewer's eyes, and it's measured in candelas per square meter (informally called "nits").  Is this what you mean by "luminance"?  Probably not, since generally, "RGB pixels" don't have this kind of luminance.  Also, there are many versions of RGB, not just sRGB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the old luminance if you have the original RGB.

Referencing https://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php for YUV to RGB conversion.

Compute U and V from original RGB:

````
```
V =  (0.439 * R) - (0.368 * G) - (0.071 * B) + 128
U = -(0.148 * R) - (0.291 * G) + (0.439 * B) + 128
```
````

`Y` is the new luminance normalized to a value between 0 and 255

Then just convert back to RGB:

```
B = 1.164(Y - 16)                   + 2.018(U - 128)
G = 1.164(Y - 16) - 0.813(V - 128) - 0.391(U - 128)
R = 1.164(Y - 16) + 1.596(V - 128)
```

Make sure you clamp your computed values of each equation to be in range of  `0..255`. Some of these formulas can convert a YUV or RGB value to something less than 0 or higher than 255.

There's also multiple formula for converting between YUV and RGB. (Different constants). I noticed the page listed above has a different computation for Y than you cited.  They are all relatively close with different precisions and adjustments.  For just changing the brightness of a pixel, almost any formula will do.

## Updated

I originally deleted this answer after the OP suggested it wasn't working for him.  I was too busy for the last few days to investigate, but I wrote some sample code to confirm my hypothesis.  At the bottom of this answer is a snippet of GDI+ based code increases the luminance of an image by a variable amount.  Along with the code is an image that I tested this out on and two conversions. One at 130% brightness.  Another at 170% brightness.

### Here's a sample conversion

**Original Image**
[image: Original Image]

**Updated Image (at 130% Y)**
[image: Updated image]

**Updated Image (at 170% Y)**
[image]

**Source:**

```
#define CLAMP(val) {val = (val > 255) ? 255 : ((val < 0) ? 0 : val);}

void Brighten(Gdiplus::BitmapData& dataIn, Gdiplus::BitmapData& dataOut, const double YMultiplier=1.3)
{
    if ( ((dataIn.PixelFormat != PixelFormat24bppRGB) && (dataIn.PixelFormat != PixelFormat32bppARGB)) ||
         ((dataOut.PixelFormat != PixelFormat24bppRGB) && (dataOut.PixelFormat != PixelFormat32bppARGB)))
    {
        return;
    }

    if ((dataIn.Width != dataOut.Width) || (dataIn.Height != dataOut.Height))
    {
        // images sizes aren't the same
        return;
    }


    const size_t incrementIn = dataIn.PixelFormat == PixelFormat24bppRGB ? 3 : 4;
    const size_t incrementOut = dataOut.PixelFormat == PixelFormat24bppRGB ? 3 : 4;
    const size_t width = dataIn.Width;
    const size_t height = dataIn.Height;


    for (size_t y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        auto ptrRowIn = (BYTE*)(dataIn.Scan0) + (y * dataIn.Stride);
        auto ptrRowOut = (BYTE*)(dataOut.Scan0) + (y * dataOut.Stride);

        for (size_t x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            uint8_t B = ptrRowIn[0];
            uint8_t G = ptrRowIn[1];
            uint8_t R = ptrRowIn[2];
            uint8_t A = (incrementIn == 3) ? 0xFF : ptrRowIn[3];

            auto Y = (0.257 * R) + (0.504 * G) + (0.098 * B) + 16;
            auto V = (0.439 * R) - (0.368 * G) - (0.071 * B) + 128;
            auto U = -(0.148 * R) - (0.291 * G) + (0.439 * B) + 128;

            Y *= YMultiplier;

            auto newB = 1.164*(Y - 16) + 2.018*(U - 128);
            auto newG = 1.164*(Y - 16) - 0.813*(V - 128) - 0.391*(U - 128);
            auto newR = 1.164*(Y - 16) + 1.596*(V - 128);

            CLAMP(newR);
            CLAMP(newG);
            CLAMP(newB);

            ptrRowOut[0] = newB;
            ptrRowOut[1] = newG;
            ptrRowOut[2] = newR;
            if (incrementOut == 4)
            {
                ptrRowOut[3] = A; // keep original alpha
            }

            ptrRowIn += incrementIn;
            ptrRowOut += incrementOut;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it does not work at all. The pixels are showed in black after saving. The luminance value was 250.

Comment: Can you show your code?  I've written plenty of YUV converters before and am confident I can spot any issues and/or correct.

Comment: Those formula might be expecting R,G,B to be in a different normalized range.  Checking.

Comment: I'm going to pull this answer until I can research his further.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @PacCol - I've confirmed that the algorithm works and updated my answer with some sample conversions.  If you are getting black pixels, make sure you are taking into account such factors as alpha channels, byte orderings (ARGB vs BGRA, stride, etc...)

Comment: @PacCol - and updated again after fixing a bug or two.