# change image brightness with c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, brightness

i want to change brightness of image, only accessing pixel value.
not using opencv function(ex. convertTo)

input : image , num

num means constant value for brightness

here is my code and result looks wierd.
Is there any problem?

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXIOR.jpg)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFCai.png)

```
cv::Mat function(cv::Mat img, int num){
    cv::Mat output;
    output = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, img.type());
    for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < img.channels(); c++)
            {
                output.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[c] = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[c] + num;
            
                if (output.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[c] > 255){
                    output.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[c] = 255;
                }
                else if (output.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[c] < 0)
                {
                    output.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[c] = 0;
                }

            }
        
        }

    }
    cv::imshow("output", output);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return img;
}
```

Comment: You're probably getting overflow wrap-around. Check for overflow before assigning to output.  `if(255- img.at...[c]) > num...`

Comment: I have a demo of converting an image's RGB bytes to YUV, scaling Y (to get more brightness), and saving back to RGB and  original file format.  It's for GDI+ instead of OpenCV, but you can probably use the same technique.  Full code is [here](https://github.com/jselbie/brighten) And the original discusson on SO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803390/how-to-get-the-calculate-the-rgb-values-of-a-pixel-from-the-luminance/62803641#62803641)

Answer (score 6):

> not using opencv function

that's somewhat silly, since your code is already using opencv's data structures.

trying to do so, you also reinvented the wheel, albeit a slightly square one ...

> Check for overflow before assigning to output.

yea that's the problem. correct way to do it would be: assign the sum to something *larger* than uchar, and *then* check

```
else if (output.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[c] < 0)
```

this will never happen, try to understand why

---

but please note, that your whole code (triple loop, omg !!!) could be rewritten as a simple:

```
Mat output = img + Scalar::all(num);
```

(faster, safer, & this will also saturate correctly !)